# prepareForSegue not being called in uitableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

The segue is going through to next screen, but prepareForSegue isn't being called, and I can't get a breakpoint to hit there.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    self.selectedObject = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showOldOrder" sender:cell];

}



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue :(id)sender

{

    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showOldOrder"])

    {

        //if you need to pass data to the next controller do it here

        // Get reference to the destination view controller

        OrderViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...

        vc.Order = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

}
```

I know the super common reasons for this not working, and have gone through all of them:

-tried `sender:nil`, `sender:self` (vc), and `sender:cell` (tablecell)

-tried just using `showOldOrder` segue directly from `uitableviewcell` to next vc and not using `didSelectRow`... same result

-`showOldOrder` is a push segue configured properly

-tablecell identifier matches in vc and storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong method  instead of your method use this below method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

you are missing "sender" that's why your method not being called.

Segues can be triggered from multiple sources, you can use the information in the segue and sender parameters to disambiguate between different logical paths in your app [Check this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepareforsegue?language=objc)

Comment: daaaaamn thanks bro! im not able to try it as i only had a few hours on friend's mac to build this, but yeah, someone had accidentally deleted function definition and retyped it (missing the other 'sender') :D thanks!